# Disable babel's escaping of characters in stringLiteral

Tags: babeljs, babel-plugin

It seems babel is doing some automatic escaping of special characters when using `t.stringLiteral` which causes problems for me. Is there any way to disable this behaviour or a workaround perhaps?

**stringBabelPlugin.js**

```
const t = require("@babel/types")

module.exports = ({ types: t }) => {
    return {
        visitor: {
            CallExpression: {
                exit(path, state) {
                    path.replaceWith(t.stringLiteral('ö'))
                },
            },
        }
    }
}
```

**stringBabelPlugin.spec.js**

```
import { pluginTester } from 'babel-plugin-tester';
import stringPlugin from './stringPlugin';


pluginTester({
  plugin: stringPlugin,
  tests: [
    {
      code: `fn("ö")`,
      output: `"ö"`,
    },
  ],
});
```

**npm test**

```
  - Expected   ""ö""
  + Received   ""\xF6";"
```

[Github repo to reproduce](https://github.com/Cottin/bug_babel_escape)